# Failed to randomize bytes using independent_bits_engine

Tags: c++

I'm trying to randomize a byte array, but it doesn't let me compile it, because of the errors below. It doesn't even work with `byte` instead of `std::uint8_t`.

> error C2338: invalid template argument for independent_bits_engine: N4659 29.6.1.1 [rand.req.genl]/1f requires one of unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long
>
> message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::independent_bits_engine<std::mt19937,8,unsigned char>' being compiled
>
> error C2338: note: char, signed char, unsigned char, char8_t, int8_t, and uint8_t are not allowed

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
void generate_random_key(std::uint8_t(&iv_buff)[N])
{
    using random_bytes_engine = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, std::uint8_t>;
    random_bytes_engine rbe;

    std::generate(std::begin(iv_buff), std::end(iv_buff), std::ref(rbe));
}
```

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/independent_bits_engine): *The effect is undefined unless the parameter is cv-unqualified and is one of unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long.* I don't know why that restriction exists, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`[rand.req.genl]/1.6`](https://eel.is/c++draft/rand.req.genl#1.6) (in the C++23 draft):

> Throughout this subclause `[rand]`, the effect of instantiating a template:

> that has a template type parameter named `UIntType` is undefined unless the corresponding template argument is cv-unqualified and is one of `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.

So, the effect is according to the standard undefined since you're not using one of the mentioned types.

You can use an `unsigned short` to get the same effect:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void generate_random_key(std::uint8_t(&iv_buff)[N])
{
    using random_bytes_engine = std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine,
                                                             CHAR_BIT, unsigned short>;
    random_bytes_engine rbe;

    std::generate(std::begin(iv_buff), std::end(iv_buff), rbe);
}
```

If you get a warning (like "*conversion from `unsigned short` to `_Ty`, possible loss of data*"), you could wrap the call to `rbe` in a lambda and do a `static_cast`:

```
    std::generate(std::begin(iv_buff), std::end(iv_buff), [&rbe]() {
        return static_cast<std::uint8_t>(rbe());
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, what about `size_t` instead of `unsigned short`, so I don't receive the warning?

Comment: @nop You're welcome! What does the warning say when you use `unsigned short`?

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\algorithm(4027,25): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'unsigned short' to '_Ty', possible loss of data`

Comment: @nop I think you will get that if you use an even bigger type like `size_t` too. You could replace `rbe` with a lambda that does a `static_cast`. I'll add that to the answer if you'd like?

Comment: Sure, but it goes away when I specify `size_t`

Comment: @nop How odd. I tried VS2019 and it warns if I use `size_t` too :-)

Comment: Do you happen to know why 8 bit types are not allowed?

Comment: @Timo No I don't know why there is this limit. I noticed this in the C++ standard some time ago myself and actually updated the documentation @ [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/independent_bits_engine) to mention this (for `independent_bits_engine` only - so there could be places @ cppreference where the `[rand]` classes/functions  still doesn't exclude `char` and `unsigned char`).